# How to filter the image data in MVC4 using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

How to display images in MVC4 from database.

Step 1:
In my code, retrieve the data and place in array class.

```
public class ImageTable
{
    public string ImageId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}

public class DataAcceess
{
    public ImageTable[] GetImages()
    {
        ImageTable[] Images = null;
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;UserID=;Password=;");

        Conn.Open();
        //SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [Product ID],ImageView1 From Cpecial_Image_tbl", Conn);

        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("Select b.[Category ID],a.[Product ID], a.[ImageView1] from Cpecial_Image_tbl as a  inner join [Cpecial_Product_tbl] as b ON a.[Product ID]=b.[Product ID]", Conn);

        SqlDataReader Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(Reader);
        Images = new ImageTable[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow Dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Images[i] = new ImageTable()
            {
                ImageId = (string)Dr["Product ID"],
                CategoryId = (string)Dr["Category ID"],
                Image = (byte[])Dr["ImageView1"]
            };
            i = i + 1;
        }


        Conn.Close();
        return Images;
    }
```

Step 2: In controller retreive the image value assign, it in byte array and return to the view like this.

```
        public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {

            // var image = db.Categories.First(m => m.CategoryID == id).Picture;

            DataAcceess objContext = new DataAcceess();

            //byte[] Image = (from a in Images select a.Image.ToArray());


            byte[] a;

            foreach (var item in objContext.GetImages())
            {
                a = item.Image;
                return File(a, "Image/jpg");
            }

               return View();
        }
```

Step 3: I added the tag in view like this
           
this will show only one image.

I want to show all the the images, and also manipulate the image with respect to the Filters
(sorting ascending , desending with catagoryId) like in shopping cart.

Could any one give me the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve every Image separately.
A return statement ends the function where you are.

Personally I would save the images on the file system and paths to them in a `ImageUrl` annotated model property.

- You can then just make a DisplayFor because the images will be a property of your Model.
- If you save your image in a Database. The database will get big and slow.